# animeJS calling non existent functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, anime.js

So I've just started out using animeJS, and I'm struggling with getting it to work. 
I'll walk through the steps I took to install it.

1. I got it through npm (`npm install animejs`)
2. Linked it using the script tag,
3. Initialized it (using `import anime from 'animejs';
   var anime = require('anime.js');`

And it still doesn't work at all, I get a type error every time, `TypeError: e.tween.easing is not a function`

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you attempt to do with it?

Comment: @Daedalus
I was trying to use it for a text animation.
To be more precise, Tobias Ahlin's text animations. 
Here's a link; https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#10